# is it possible to install a simple proxy webserver on a VPS to bypass a blocked port?

Tags: proxy, web-hosting, portforwarding

My webhosting company serves up Control Panel on a funky port number (20000 or something).  This port is blocked from work, so I cannot access Control Panel during the day (in case of emergency).

Is it possible, and is there an easy way to run a simple proxy on a VPS so I can browse to the VPS on port 80 and have it talk to the Control Panel machine on the funky port 20000?

Any suggestions are helpful!

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a SSH-forward:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:20000 user@yourhost
```

You can access your config interface using **http://localhost:8080**

You can create such a tunnel using Putty on Windows, too. http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't quite get it (I'm thick). If I need to communicate with the remote sevrer on 20000 and that port is blocked on my local network, how is the local process that accepts the request localhost:8080 capable of talking to the remote server on 20000? Sorry I guess I need a clearer picture.

Comment: You connect to your server via ssh (Port 22). This connection can tunnel arbitrary data, that means, every request to localhost:8080 is forwarded using this tunnel to the localhost on the other side, port 20000.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run the ssh tunnel on the remote server. Just login using ssh, and run: ssh -L 80:localhost:20000 user@yourserver and reach your server using http://yourserver:80/.

Comment: So let me get this straight. :) I set up a VPS on the web ('yourhost') that is accepting SSH requests. I run this SSH command locally on my Windows box. This command establishes a tunnel between my Windows box and the remote VPS. When I browse with firefox to http: //www.abc123.com:8080 , this is actually a request to my local machine on port 8080 which is the SSH tunnel, and it causes the VPS (at the other end of the tunnel) to browse to http: //www.abc123.com:20000 and return the results to me on my local machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, basically. Just add the tunnel options to the Putty options (Connections / SSH / Tunnels).